# MySQL Union error

Tags: mysql, union

Why do i get this error with this query?

```
SELECT distinct fileID 
FROM ( SELECT fileID from file order by fileID desc limit 30) as R1 
UNION (SELECT fileID from visit order by counter desc limit 30 ) 
WHERE status = 1 order by rand() LIMIT 10
```

error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE status = 1 order by rand() LIMIT 10' at line 1

what i want is to select the top 30 most viewed file and top 30 most recent file and then randomly select from them limit by 10 with the file status = 1.

Comment: better explain what you want to achieve with that query. i can point out where the parse error is, but the query screams there is a more serious misconception in it.

Comment: sorry i wasn't clear enough, what i want is to select the top 30 most viewed file and top 30 most recent file and then randomly select from them limit by 10 with the file status = 1.

Comment: Do both tables `file` and `visit` have a `status` column?

Comment: @ypercube no, the fileid on visit table is related to the audio table's fileid.

Comment: does visit hold a single row for each visit? is `visit.counter` an auto_increment field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put your two queries for newest files and most visits in a UNION inside a subquery, and then reorder the resulting derived table by RAND and limit the result to 10.

Note:

you state you want to select recently visited files.. but ordering by "counter" in fact selects the files with the most visits .. not the recent ones.

```
SELECT DISTINCT fileID 
FROM (
  SELECT file.fileID 
    FROM file 
    WHERE file.status = 1 
    ORDER BY file.fileID DESC 
    LIMIT 30
  UNION ALL
  SELECT visit.fileID 
    FROM visit 
      JOIN file ON file.fileID = visit.fileID 
    WHERE file.status = 1 
    ORDER BY visit.counter DESC 
    LIMIT 30 
) dt
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 10
```

As a reaction to the OPs comment, i added a JOIN in one of the selects to check if the file related to a visit has status = 1.

Also Note:

for this query to perform fast on larger amounts of data you should add index on the fields `file.status` and `visit.counter`. If `fileID` is not already a key / index for those tables, you should add an index on this field too.

---

The `visit.file_id` is not `UNIQUE` so the above query may have the same file_ids in the sub-result of the 2nd subquery (the duplicates will be removed by the final `DISTINCT` but that means that the second `LIMIT 30` does not work as wanted). Possible correction:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fileID 
FROM (
  SELECT file.fileID 
    FROM file 
    WHERE file.status = 1 
    ORDER BY file.fileID DESC 
    LIMIT 30
  UNION ALL
  SELECT visit.fileID 
    FROM visit 
      JOIN file ON file.fileID = visit.fileID 
    WHERE file.status = 1 
    GROUP BY visit.fileId
    ORDER BY MAX(visit.counter) DESC 
    LIMIT 30 
) dt
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: the status row is only at the **file** table and not on **visit**.

Comment: fixed. then it belongs even more inside the subquery and not outside.

Comment: that is the alias for the derived table. this is required by mysql. can also be written as `(SELECT ...) AS dt` .. the `AS` is optional in this case.

Comment: the fileid on visit table is related to the audio table's fileid and i want to also check if the fileid on the visit has the status set to 1. i also fixed the code above for parenthesis.

Comment: i don't know which parenthesis you mean, the only one necessary is already in my answer.. 

to check if `file` row that is related to a `visit` you need to use a JOIN .. i added this in my latest edit.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. It may need some modification (depending on Uniqueness of the file_id) but it will do what the OP wants.

Comment: now i get this ** Column 'fileID' in field list is ambiguous ** :( . this errors are new to me so pardon.

Comment: @xiomai that is because we are now messing with multiple tables which have the field names in the same select. i fixed this in my edit by prefixing all fields with the correct table name.

Comment: See my edit. @Kaii: I took the liberty of adding a variation.

Comment: i didn't want to go too far (in fact i already did) with assumptions. since we now have the information from the OP that the fileID in the votes table is not unique, we can assume each entry represents a single visit. (however, i don't understand why there is a "counter" then) if you want to do it 100% correct, you should react on the OPs wish to select from the **most recent** visits. the only thing you did is fix the **most visits** query, which was already wrong in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do with this query? I think, there is more parsing errors.

I don't know if MySQL takes this.. ..and if is that You want to do...

```
    SELECT distinct fileID FROM (( SELECT fileID from file order by
fileID desc limit 10) as R1 UNION (SELECT fileID from visit order by
counter desc limit 10 ) as R2) WHERE R1.status = 1 order by R1.rand() LIMIT 10
```

Comment: does this mean all the 20 union results would be randomly selected with your R1.rand() ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you need to parentheses to close the select.

```
SELECT DISTINCT fileid
FROM   ((SELECT fileid, status 
         FROM   FILE
         ORDER  BY fileid DESC
         LIMIT  10)
        UNION
        (SELECT fileid, status 
         FROM   visit
         ORDER  BY counter DESC
         LIMIT  10)) AS T
WHERE  status = 1
ORDER  BY Rand()
LIMIT  10
```

Comment: 1. each derived table (subquery) must have an alias  2. there is no resulting field status outside the subquery on which a WHERE cause can be applied

Comment: i tried but i get this. **Every derived table must have its own alias**. i know i should put **AS** somewhere but i don't know where.

Comment: @xiomai Yep, I missed the alias, fixed.

Comment: now i get ** Unknown column `status` in `where clause` ** . i tried using audio.status or t.status but still get same error.

Comment: @xiaomai  Yes, you have to select status out in the sub query, is it in both table ?

Comment: @Kaii Add status to the subquery, check again.

Comment: @xdazz visit table has no status row because it is related to file table's fileid.